# How can I rearrange the numerical data of some columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I whant is to rearrange the numerical data in column for example BookID. If I have column with data like this:

```
BookID ; BookTitle
  1         name1
  4         name2
 11        name3
```

How can I rearrange to look like this:

```
BookID ; BookTitle
 0         name1
 1         name2
 2         name3
```

Comment: Do you want to change the value of the entries' ID? Why do you want to do this? Are you sure that the change will not cause unpredicted results? Will you update all references to the ID's? How? Why? **OR** Do you just want to query the entries with their row number?

Comment: Just to change numbers from BookID , in second column must stay data as they were

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select row_number() over (order by BookId) - 1 as BookId, BookTitle
from books b;
```

If you want to change the ids in the data, you *can* do that.  But, it is not recommended.  The primary key on a row does not need to have any meaning.  It gets used for foreign key references in other tables, for instance, and if you change the value in the original table, you need to change it there as well.

Comment: I think You can add row_number() - 1 in your query, since it starts with 0 in the example

Comment: When I do this the result is just like this:                        BookID ; BookTitle
   0         name1
   1         name2
   2         name3        > but it is not save changes , when I select * from books . Result is like in first table

Comment: @dejan . . . That is because I strongly, strongly, strongly discourage you from changing primary keys on records after they have been created.

Answer (score 0):

To update BookID in sequential order. Use the below update query.

```
UPDATE A SET A.BookID = B.NewBookID 
FROM Books A 
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT BookID, NewBookID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BookTitle) - 1
            FROM Books
           ) AS B 
ON A.BookID = B.BookID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can renumber using a common table expression and a ranking function:

```
;WITH ranked AS
(
    SELECT BookID
    , NewBookID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BookTitle) -1
    FROM books
)
UPDATE ranked
SET BookID = NewBookID;
```

modified as per expected result